# How to import Material Components Web Select Menu JS component

Tags: javascript, material-components, material-components-web

Trying to get a [Material Web Component Select Menu](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/select-menus/) to behave according to [its demo](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/select) but it seems the documentation does not include *which* JS components to import.

I have tried `import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';`, following convention with its other Web components but I get an uncaught reference error: `ReferenceError: mdc is not defined`.

I seem to be missing a base class or I'm importing the wrong JS component but *am not sure which to include*.

Does anybody have knowledge about this?

### Update - 10/26/2018

I posted this question on Github and received [a response](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/3995#issuecomment-433257419). I believe it is the correct implementation as it hasn't thrown any errors but a previous bug has kept me from fully testing of this approach.

I will return to this question as soon as I can test the suggested answer in the above link.

Comment: Hard to know what is really happening without seeing some code, but here is a link to [docs for js instantiation for mdc-select](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select#javascript-instantiation) and [another general link for importing mdc js components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/importing-js.md#importing-the-js-component).

Comment: Which framework are you using? React? Angular? Vue?

Comment: @Manu - I am not using any framework. I'm trying to do things in the browser as compatible as possible (and with the appropriate polyfills).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this example,it will help. It need just mdc instance to initiate the mdc-select.

```
      > https://codepen.io/cubetastic/pen/ZoPNKK
```